# Cache JPA Entities with EJB

Tags: jpa, ejb, jpa-2.0, ejb-3.1

*[The real question is marked in **bold** down. Here follows an as short as possible explanation of my situation]*

I have the following JPA Entities:

```
@Entity Genre{
 private String name;
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "genre", cascade={CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
 private Collection<Novel> novels;
}
@Entity
class Novel{
 @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
 private Genre genre;
 private String titleUnique;
 @OneToMany(mappedBy="novel", cascade={CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
 private Collection<NovelEdition> editions;
}
@Entity
class NovelEdition{
 private String publisherNameUnique;
 private String year;
 @ManyToOne(optional=false, cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
 private Novel novel;
 @ManyToOne(optional=false, cascade={CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
 private Catalog appearsInCatalog;
}
@Entity
class Catalog{
 private String name;
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "appearsInCatalog", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
 private Collection<NovelEdition> novelsInCatalog;
}
```

The idea is to have several *Novels*, belonging each to a specific *Genre*, for which can exist more than an edition (different publisher, year, etc). For semplicity a *NovelEdition* can belong to just 
one *Catalog*, being such a Catalog represented by such a text file:

```
Catalog: Name Of Catalog 1
-----------------------
"Title of Novel 1", "Genre1 name","Publisher1 Name", 2009
"Title of Novel 2", "Genre1 name","Pulisher2 Name", 2010
.....

Catalog: Name Of Catalog 2
-----------------------
"Title of Novel 1", "Genre1 name","Publisher2 Name", 2011
"Title of Novel 2", "Genre1 name","Pulisher1 Name", 2011
.....
```

Each entity has associated a Stateless EJB that acts as a DAO, using a Transaction Scoped EntityManager. For example:

```
@Stateless
public class NovelDAO extends AbstractDAO<Novel> {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "XXX")
    private EntityManager em;

    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public NovelDAO() {
        super(Novel.class);
    }
    //NovelDAO Specific methods
}
```

*I am interested at when the catalog files are parsed and the corresponding entities are built* (I usually read a whole batch of Catalogs at a time).

Being the parsing a String-driven procedure, I don't want to repeat actions like *novelDAO.getByName("Title of Novel 1")* so I *would like to use a centralized cache for mappings of type String-Identifier->Entity object.*

Currently I use 3 Objects:
1) The file parser, which does something like:

```
final CatalogBuilder catalogBuilder = //JNDI Lookup
//for each file:
String catalogName = parseCatalogName(file);
catalogBuilder.setCatalogName(catalogName);
//For each novel edition
String title= parseNovelTitle();
String genre= parseGenre();
...
catalogBuilder.addNovelEdition(title, genre, publisher, year);
//End foreach
catalogBuilder.build();
```

2) The CatalogBuilder is a Stateful EJB which uses the Cache and gets re-initialized each time a new Catalog file is parsed and gets "removed" after a catalog is persisted.

```
@Stateful
public class CatalogBuilder {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "XXX", type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    private EntityManager em;
    @EJB
    private Cache cache;
    private Catalog catalog;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
      catalog = new Catalog();
      catalog.setNovelsInCatalog(new ArrayList<NovelEdition>());
    }

    public void addNovelEdition(String title, String genreStr, String publisher, String year){
        Genre genre = cache.findGenreCreateIfAbsent(genreStr);//**
        Novel novel = cache.findNovelCreateIfAbsent(title, genre);//**
        NovelEdition novEd = new NovelEdition();
        novEd.setNovel(novel);
        //novEd.set publisher year catalog
        catalog.getNovelsInCatalog().add();
    }

    public void setCatalogName(String name) {
        catalog.setName(name);
    }

    @Remove
    public void build(){
        em.merge(catalog);
    }
}
```

3) **Finally, the problematic bean: Cache**. For CatalogBuilder I used an EXTENDED persistence context (which I need as the Parser executes several succesive transactions) together with a Stateful EJB; 
but in this case I am not really sure what I need. In fact, **the cache**:

1. *Should stay in memory until the parser is finished with its job,
   but not longer (should not be a singleton) as the parsing is just a
   very particular activity which happens rarely.*
2. *Should keep all of
   the entities in context, and should return managed entities form
   methods marked with **, otherwise the attempt to persist the catalog
   should fail (duplicated INSERTs)..*
3. *Should use the same
   persistence context as the CatalogBuilder.*

What I have now is :

```
@Stateful
public class Cache {

   @PersistenceContext(unitName = "XXX", type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    private EntityManager em;

    @EJB
    private sessionbean.GenreDAO genreDAO;
    //DAOs for other cached entities

    Map<String, Genre> genreName2Object=new TreeMap<String, Genre>();

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize(){
    for (Genre g: genreDAO.findAll()) {
      genreName2Object.put(g.getName(), em.merge(g));
    }
    }

    public Genre findGenreCreateIfAbsent(String genreName){
     if (genreName2Object.containsKey(genreName){
       return genreName2Object.get(genreName);
    }
    Genre g = new Genre();
    g.setName();
    g.setNovels(new ArrayList<Novel>());
    genreDAO.persist(t);
    genreName2Object.put(t.getIdentifier(), em.merge(t));
return t;
}
}
```

But honestly **I couldn't find a solution which satisfies these 3 points at the same time**. For example, using another **stateful bean with an extended persistence context** would work for the 1st parsed file, but I have
no idea what should happen from the 2nd file on.. Indeed for the first file the PC will be created and propagated from *CatalogBuilder* to *Cache*, which will then use the same PC. But after build() returns,
the PC of CatalogBuilder should (I guess) be removed and re-created during the successive parsing, although the PC of Cache should stay "alive": shouldn't in this case an exception being thrown? Another problem is
what to do when the Cache bean is passivated. Currently I get the exception:

```
"passivateEJB(), Exception caught -> 
java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException
    at com.sun.ejb.base.io.IOUtils.serializeObject(IOUtils.java:101)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.util.cache.LruSessionCache.saveStateToStore(LruSessionCache.java:501)"
```

Hence, I have no idea how to implement my cache. How would you solve the problem?

Comment: Are you not interested in the L2 shared-cache used by the JPA to share a cached entities between the PersistenceContexts?

Comment: Hi! As far as I understood L2 cache is enabled by default in EclipseLink. To make sure to activate it, I added <shared-cache-mode>ALL</shared-cache-mode> to my persistence.xml. Shouldn't the result of each query be automatically cached then? I changed my Cache class to query directly the DB (throught DAOs'methods) instead of storing the values into Maps, but with a FINE log level I can see the SQL queries are executed every time I call a findXXXCreateIfAbsent() method.. What is wrong in this approach?

Answer (score 0):

**EclipseLink configuration :**

- You can have specify property in configuration file for all entites.

  `<property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="true"/>`
- At entity level with `@Cache` annotation, specifying different attributes.

**General JPA configuration :**

- At entity level by using `@Cacheable` annotation with `value` attribute as `true`.
- Specifying the retrieval mode by `CacheRetrieveMode`, attribute `USE` to enable else `BYPASS`.

  `entityManager.setProperty("javax.persistence.cache.retrieveMode", CacheRetrieveMode.USE);`
- Configuring the storage in cache by `CacheStoreMode` with attribute `BYPASS`, `USE` or `REFRESH`.

  `entityManager.setProperty("javax.persistence.cache.storeMode",CacheStoreMode.REFRESH);`
- `Cache` interface represents shared cache. To remove all or some cached entity, you can call one of the evict methods. You can get reference of cache interface from `EntityManagerFactory`.